# How can I get notifications from the clipboard?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Is there a way to be notified when the content of the clipboard changes?
I looked a class "Clipboard". It has numerous methods to set the clipboard content but no event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in the Framework, I believe.  You can do it with Win32, though.  Look into `SetClipboardViewer` in User32.dll:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);
```

It gets a little involved.  It isn't a straightforward notification, but a message chain; you'll need to pass the notification on to the next receiver.

[This article](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx) has a good description of the steps necessary.