# Overriding the Copy-Paste capability under Windows OS?

Tags: copy, copy-paste, paste

I'm pretty sure that's a very difficult task. Did anyone out there know how we can overrides the copy-paste capability under Windows OS?

(Overriding for the complete environment... patching the Windows OS itself.)

Ex : Trim the copied text after copying it.

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't explain exactly what you need to do, there's no way to understand what you want so there's no way to answer the question.

Comment: the question has been answered perfectly below. thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you haven't specified the language. Here's how you might in VB.NET (put this in a `Timer`'s `Tick` handler):

```
If Clipboard.ContainsText() Then
     Dim s As String = Clipboard.GetText()
     Dim t As String = s.Trim()
     If s <> t Then Clipboard.SetText(t) 'Trim all text, for example
End If
```

Comment: Of course, those who hate polling solutions might prefer using a windows hook to handle the clipboard events.  This is in fact possible in VB.NET/C# via interop, though it's rather ugly.

Comment: I wouldn't post that without knowing the language he wants, though ;)

Comment: Oh thank you so much minitech! I haven't thought of doing it that way! VB.net will be fine thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that you actually need to patch the OS itself, considering that Windows always provides the ability to hook on the clipboard events directly and override them however you wish.  See [How to get a clipboard paste notification and provide my own data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298209/how-to-get-a-clipboard-paste-notification-and-provide-my-own-data) .